# How to set the default Java version in the Project Structure in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I see that whenever I open a new project, the Java version in the Project Structure is automatically set to 13.

[image]

Currently, I go over all the modules and change their Java versions to 8. Do you know how can I make IntelliJ automatically set the Java version in the Project Structure to 13?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure a *Default Project Structure*, which will be default for every new project you open/create/import in the future:

For this:

1. First of all, I would recommend to have an updated version of your IntelliJ IDEA;
2. Go to `File → New Projects Settings → Structure for New Projects`. Here you will be able to configure your default *Project SDK* and *Project language level*.

Hence, all the new projects you are going to open in IntelliJ IDEA, will, by default, have the settings you have configured.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply any Java version for current project as:

`File -> Project Structure ->` In **Project Setting** select `Project ->` In the right side, select **SDK** at **Project SDK**; in **Project language level**, choose the **version of Java** so that IntelliJ can automatically suggest code for you.

Hope it works!

Comment: I think OP mentions that he/she already does what you wrote here. They ask specifically for setting the Java version for all the projects, as a default.

Answer (score 0):

The place to set default project SDK in IntelliJ IDEA version 2023.1.3 is `File / New Projects Setup / Structure / Project Settings / Project /`:
[image]